# Ghostscript - PDF to image - Weird bold text

Tags: ghostscript

I am not sure, how to describe the problem. I generate a pdf with mpdf. I have a title line with a bold text and in the PDF everything looks fine.

Here is how the text (or part of it looks in the PDF):

[image]

Now i try to convert it with ghostscript to jpg:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r600 -sOutputFile=image.jpg pdf.pdf
```

And the text looks good, but there is a weird line inside it:

[image]

If I change the text to non bold and convert it, everything is ok

[image]

Any ideas how th fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text isn't really bold. By which I mean its not using a bold font.

Its 'fake bold' and has been created either by drawing the text twice, or by creating a path from the text and both stroking and filling that path, or by drawing the text as text, and stroking the path as well. Without seeing the PDF file I can't, obviously, be sure which approach is being used.

Your problem is that you are using `-dTextAlphaBits=4` and `-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4`, that 'anti-aliases' both text and graphics **as it is drawn** by blending it with the existing background. So what you are seeing is the boundary between the two objects being dran in such a way that the intersection ends up partially showing the background.

Turn off those two switches and try again.

If you are going to JPEG then there's really no point in using those two switches, the output will be quite blurred enough already.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. The i didn't include the bold version of the font